# ConstraintLayout with Flow helper - Particular alignments of views

Tags: android-constraintlayout

I'm using a constraint layout with a Flow helper in order to automatically create a new line to display some views if there is not enough place. But I would like to always put the last view to the right of the screen, like in this picture (https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvEhZ.png):

It seems that using a flow is not compatible with the alignment properties (like layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent") because the black rectangle is displayed on the left if a new line is created.

Here is a part of the code:

```
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/BT_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8sp"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"/>

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/BT_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16sp"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"/>

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/BT_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16sp"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"/>

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/BT_4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16sp"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"/>

        <android.widget.Space
            android:id="@+id/SP_End"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"/>

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/BT_End"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="BT_1,BT_2,BT_3,BT_4,SP_End,BT_End"
            app:flow_horizontalGap="10dp"
            app:flow_horizontalStyle="packed"
            app:flow_horizontalBias="0"
            app:flow_verticalBias="0"
            app:flow_wrapMode="chain"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Please note that I tried with or without the 0 width space.

So, how to manage particular alignments in a constraint layout combined with a flow helper?